# Name of the schema I'm currently using sqlplus

Tags: oracle11g

I'm logged in as sysdba and I'd like to know which schema I'm using
If I create a table as sysdba how to see in which schema was created.

Comment: If you create a table when you are logged as `SYSDBA`, and, during the creation of the table, you won't specify the schema for that table, then the table will be created in `SYSDBA` schema (because it's the schema of the user you are logged as).

Answer (score 1):

To return the current schema use:

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'current_schema') FROM dual;
```